# Using google analytics goals to optimise goals in adwords

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, google-ads

We have set up goals in analytics to do with time on site, we also have an adwords campaign running, i noticed in adwords you can set up a conversion in adwords.

But this only works by putting code into a 'thank you' page that the user sees when they have completed an action.

I was wandering if you can set up in adwords a conversion being a certain time on site ?

Comment: Maybe not helpful you must have it in Adwords but you could achieve a report in Analytics which would do this for you if that is any use. You can create an engagement goal where the time is great than a certain value and then segment that traffic from Adwords.

Comment: @joesk when you say segment the traffic, do you mean look at the people that stayed for say 1min+ then look at the terms they used, then taylor the negative keywords, pricing, location and other variables to capture more 1min+ visitors and less -5sec / bounce visitors ?

Comment: Hi Sam - So my comment was really a guideline on how to create create a goal for Adwords traffic which remained on the site longer than a certain period of time. What your follow on comment refers to (I think) is what to do with that information. I can't really be of much help here I'm afraid as you would need to understand the overall picture.